# Updating records confusion with html5 and sqlite

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite

I have a page where a user inputs information in forms.  When the user clicks submit, this form data is saved to the database and each submit creates a row in my table.  These rows are then displayed on a records page in a JQM listview.  Now my problem is, I need a function which when a user clicks on a list element, they are able to go back to that page where they input information and update that record.

I understand how to get the information from each record, but what I don't understand is whether to create a new page which is exactly the same as the input page and then make the submit button update rather than add to the database?  Or whether there is a way to go to the same page and make the button update rather than add a new record.  For further clarity, this is the HTML of the input page:

```
<a data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-right" id="submit" onClick="javascript:AddValueToDB()">Submit</a>
```

so this adds all the information the user has inputted into the database.  But to update this information, can I change the function of the onclick or would I have to create a duplicate page which does UpdateDBValues() onclick.

I appreciate this may be difficult to understand, but I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the onclick event after it has fired the first one you can do this using javascript inside your first function.

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() { anotherFunction(); }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LL7mU/

Comment: What happens if I want to add another record from the input page after updating the other one?

Comment: The button can only fire one event. If you want to add another record then you would need another button. Instead of changing the onclick, maybe you want to add another button to update and leave the first one as is.

Comment: I see, so if I didn't want to have two buttons on that page, one for update and one for add, would it be ok to make a duplicate page which just updates the records when the button is pressed?  With that page only being called if a record from the listview is clicked.  Appreciate your time

Comment: Adding a button to the page when the listview is clicked would be easier then a whole new page. Remember the onclick only changes when the user has added. If they refresh the page then its back to the add record button again. Alternativly you could still have one button and then use that for adding and updating, validating in the javascript / sql save function

Comment: I like the idea of using the button for both adding and updating and determining which one it should be from the javascript.  Thanks for the help, I'll try and implement it